# How to Increase Clip Board Value in C# Code, Using Jitbit Macro Recorder

Tags: c#

I'm using Jitbit Macro Recorder to do some web automation task, I need to multiply clip board value, but in jitbit macro recorder need the C# code to do this. Anyone can help please.

Comment: Show what you have tried and explain what went wrong with it

Comment: i dont know c# code, so i use macro recorder to open the calculator and copy and paste the value to browser.

Answer (score 3):

I've not played with Jitbit Macro Recorder, but the documentation is pretty clear.
Something like this should do it:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double value;
        if(double.TryParse(Clipboard.GetText(), out value))
        {
            value *= 2; //change '2' to what ever you need it to be!
            Clipboard.SetText(value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Footnote: I've not tested this code at all so I cannot guarantee it'll work. It should set you off on the right foot though!

Comment: Actually i need to multiply the clipboard value by 2.5, ex: clipboard current value is 1, i need to multiply it to 2.5, eqals to 2.50, with 2 decimal digit.

Comment: You should be able to edit the code as you need. Not sure why the downvote though...